# Trying to take picture in Xamarin.Android and keep in image view not working

Tags: android, xamarin

Im trying to take a picture with the camera from inside an app I am building. When you click on a button it should bring you too a new page and the camera should open.

The camera is being opened and you can take a picture, but this is where I get the error saying System.NullReferenceException.

I am trying to keep this picture in a image view and allow the user to view it.

my axml page is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewOfCamera"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/addphoto_btn_uploadPhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload Photo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my activity page

```
public class AddPhoto : Activity
{
    ImageView imvCamera;        

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        imvCamera = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.viewOfCamera);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, 
    [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
        imvCamera.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: which specific line is causing the exception?

Comment: @Jason the 2nd last line?

Comment: @Jason its actually the very last line that is causing the app to break. Im trying to set the captured image to the one that I take